# Fix for System Tray and other elements constant flickering?

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

This has been going on for weeks. A reboot fixes it temporarily, but it comes back within a day or two. Most of the time it's just really annoying, but sometimes it actually affects my work. For instance, I was trying to debug an app in Visual Studio and this flicker was affecting the "Attach Process" dialog while trying to scroll through the list of processes.

Dell XPS 15 9510, All drivers up to date, including Nvidia.

Interestingly, restarting Windows Explorer does NOT fix the issue.

Any ideas appreciated....

[image]

Comment: I literally said all drivers are up to date. I run Support Assist at least once a week and update everything. I have probably updated the BIOS twice since this started happening.

Comment: If you can screen cap it, it's not likely to be a hardware issue [if that helps at all].

Comment: I suspect it's a piece of software I have running that has a memory leak, I just haven't been able to identify it yet. The next time it starts (I just rebooted), I'm going to slowly end processes one by one and see if I can figure out what is causing it.

Top suspects are Cmder, OneDrive, and Spotify.

Comment: I already ran Dell diagnostics, extensive, and it found nothing. This means contacting Dell would be a waste of time as they won't do anything if Diagnostics doesn't find anything. It's almost definitely a software problem.

Comment: Update: I think it might be Greenshot. Will confirm if I can replicate again.

Comment: Looks like it is known! https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/issues/348

Answer (score 0):

I have 100% confirmed this is due to the application "Greenshot", 1.2.10 Build 6 (the latest build tagged "stable"). It only happens while there is image data in the clipboard. A quick workaround is to copy some plain text.  [This was a known issue in the current "stable" release](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/issues/348), but  appears it has been fixed in "1.3.274 unstable".

Comment: I use the stable version a lot, and never had this problem. Why do you need the unstable version?

Comment: I'm glad you don't have this issue, but I do. This was a known issue in 1.2.10. The only reason I "need" then unstable version is to see if it fixes the issue, which it appears it has.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue has been resolved.
Anyhow, I recommend using <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, instead of any 3rd party apps.